# Laravel - Multiple Arrays for Multiple Recipients (Mailable/Notifications)

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, notifications

I'm looking for advice for a project and an interesting predicament I've put myself in.

I have multiple fields in my shipment model, they are:

- shipto_id
- shipfrom_id
- billto_id

They all link (through different relationships) to my customer model:

```
public function billtoAccount()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'bill_to');
}

public function shiptoAccount()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'ship_to');
}

public function shipfromAccount()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'ship_from');
}
```

and these customers (in reality would likely be better described as customer accounts (these are NOT USER ACCOUNTS, they're more just like a profile for each company that business is done with)) can have a multitude of users associated with them.

```
 public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Now, while I know how to send off mailables and notifications, I was curious to know how I would go about sending off those to multiple user's emails. So let me describe the following: Something is created and the following customers (and in turn, their users) are referenced.

- (billto_id) - Customer Account 1 - User 1 (email1@example.com)
- (shipto_id) - Customer Account 2 - User 2 (email2@example.com) & User 3 (email3@example.com)
- (shipfrom_id) - Customer Account 37 - User 6 (email4@example.com)

Now, how would I go about moving the emails of the users over to an array of emails to have a notification or mailable sent to them?

So it should pop out: email1@example.com, email2@example.com, email3@example.com, email4@examples.com

Comment: Can't you just loop through the three relationships and get the emails from the related models?   Might want to get away from the mindset that this should be an eloquent relationship and not just a method that performs this logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on @Devon 's comment: 
This is business logic. You could have a method on your Shipment model that returns the customer instances to be notified as an array, e.g. `getNotifiables() : array`

Then in your Customer model you may use the Notifiable trait

`use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;`

And looping over your Notifiables, i.e. Customers

```
$notification = new ShipmentWasCreated()
foreach ($shipment->getNotifiables() as $notifiable) {
    $notifiable->notify($notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better alternative:

```
Notification::send($shipment->getNotifiables(), new ShipmentWasCreated());
```